# Need to migrate 900Gb data from dynamodb into BigQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-migration, amazon-dynamodb

I have around 900Gb data in dynamodb table. need to migrate to BigQ as the cost of storing data is very high on DynamoDB. can anyone tell me the efficient way to migrate with lowest cost.

Comment: BQ and dynamo DB haven't the same feature. Are you sure that the migration that you want?

Answer (score 0):

Talking a bout Google Cloud, you have a [Price Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=e7431a72-25fb-4ba4-a08f-196de1a84c42) which will give you an estimate of the monthly price for your application based on the location, Storage, and, for your case, the querys.

And here a guide of how to [migrate from DynamoDB to Cloud Sapanner](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/migrating-dynamodb-to-cloud-spanner), which is it similar.